# How do I return a not found in filter function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching a value through `html table`.

When I click a button, I am executing the code below:

```
var userinput = $(input).val();
$('table td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == '654';
}).css('background-color', 'yellow');

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>654</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code above works but I also want to **know if there was no value returned OR the value does not exist** inside one of the *td* in the table.

By the way, the value that is searched is dynamic.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can't you just set some var then inspect that before returning?  or am i misunderstanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result returned by the `filter()` and check the length to determine if found or not:

```js
var userinput = '654';
var resArr = $('table td').filter(function(){ 
  return $(this).text() == userinput;
}).css('background-color', 'yellow').get();
var token = resArr.length > 0 ? 'Found' : 'Not Found';
console.log(token);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>654</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can attach *input* event to check each *td* like the following:

```js
$('#txtInput').on('input', function(){
  $('td').css('background-color', '')
  var userinput = $(this).val();
  var resArr = $('table td').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() == userinput;
  }).css('background-color', 'yellow').get();
  var token = resArr.length > 0 ? 'Found' : 'Not Found';
  console.clear();
  console.log(token);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" placeholder="Enter to search"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>654</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun, the value that I am searching is dynamic and not limited to 654. Can you see a way of searching throught the table element with the value?

Comment: @ConanCarroll, I have added another answer... may be that could give you an idea of what you want to achieve....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this!

```js
var userinput = $('input').val();
$('table td').filter(function(){
if($(this).text() == '654'){ 
  return $(this).text() == '654';
}
else {
  alert('Not Found');
}
}).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>652</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>456</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi CodeGator. What if 654 is dynamic, can you update your code with userinput variable?

Comment: You can take $('#dynamic_value').text() instead of static value on click. If it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mimic other functions like `.indexOf()`.

```
function strInTable(t, str){
  $("tr", t).each(function(ind, el){
    if($("td", el).text().trim() == str){
      return ind;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var userStr = $(input).val();
var loc = strInTable($("table"), userStr);
if(loc >= 0){
  console.log("Query Found: '" + userStr + "', Row " + loc);
  $("table tr:eq(" + loc +")").css('background-color', 'yellow');
} else {
  console.log("Query Not Found: '" + userStr + ".);
}
```

If you get `-1` the value is not found (false). If it is found, an integer is returned with the row index that the value was found.

```js
$(function() {
  function strInTable(t, str) {
    console.log("Needle: " + str);
    var result = -1;
    $("tr", t).each(function(ind, el) {
      if ($("td", el).text().trim() == str) {
        console.log("Found Needle. Return: " + ind);
        result = ind;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  $("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userStr = $("#user-input").val();
    var loc = strInTable($("table"), userStr);
    console.log("Search Result: " + loc);
    $("table tr").css("background", "");
    if (loc >= 0) {
      console.log("Query Found: '" + userStr + "', Row " + loc);
      $("table tr:eq(" + loc + ")").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else {
      console.log("Query Not Found: '" + userStr + "'.");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
  Search: <input type="text" id="user-input" /><button type="submit" id="go-btn">Find</button>
</form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>654</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope that helps.